# Replacing spaces with tabs in vim

Tags: vim

I have a `fil1.tsv` file, from which I copied few contents to a new new file `file2.tsv`.
(Using ctrl+shift+V)

While copying, the existing `TAB` characters have been replaces with spaces, due to the below lines in the `.vimrc` file

```
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4 expandtab smarttab
```

Is it possible to replace these spaces with `TAB` character again?
Currently, the copied version has problems when reading using pandas' `read_csv()` function. It reads all the columns as single one.

Comment: I've not tried but I think you should be able to use `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+')` directly in pandas. It doesn't answer your question though.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work as there were text contents with spaces involved.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:retab: `:set noexpandtab` and `:retab!`

Comment: Then you have a bigger problem, as you have to know which spaces came from the tabs and which spaces are in the string. Either, you can copy again and do: `set noexpandtab` before pasting, or you can (if you don't have the original copy) try: `:% s/    /\t/g`. (phd's answer is probably better.)

Comment: @phd.... It works, thanks a lot. I tried the same command before, but had used `:retab` instead of `:retab!`